# j2me splash screen

Tags: java-me, splash-screen

How to build an image-based splash screen for my j2me application?

I already have an application and I need an splash screen to attach with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
class SplashScreenSwitcher extends Thread {  

    private Display display;
    private Displayable splashScreen;
    private Displayable nextScreen;

    public SplashScreenSwitcher(Display display, Displayable splashScreen, Displayable nextScreen) {
         this.display = display;
         this.splashScreen = splashScreen;
         this.nextScreen = nextScreen;
    }

    public void run() {
         display.setCurrent(splashScreen);
         try {
              Thread.sleep(2000); //Here you set needed time or make a constant
         } catch (Exception ex) {}
         display.setCurrent(nextScreen);
    }
}
```

So, all you do is just create a new instance of this class and start the Thread.

Answer (score 3):

There is no default 'splash screen' method for J2ME, it involves just showing a picture for a few seconds then carrying on with the next display. If you really want you can use the time to load some other things in the background.

[This is a tutorial by Sun on splash screens](http://java.sun.com/developer/J2METechTips/2001/tt0820.html)